# Where did I go wrong with this trig integration?

Tags: integration, algebra-precalculus

$$\int^\frac \pi3_ \frac \pi6 \frac1{(\sqrt3 \cos{x} +\sin{x})^2}dx$$
$$=\frac 12\int^\frac \pi3_ \frac \pi6 \frac 1{\cos^2{(x-\frac \pi6)}}dx$$
$$=\frac 12\int^\frac \pi3_ \frac \pi6 \sec^2{\left(x-\frac \pi6\right)}dx$$
$$=\frac 12 \left[\tan{\left(x-\frac \pi6\right)}\right]^\frac \pi 3 _\frac \pi6$$
$$=\frac 1{2\sqrt3}$$
However, the answer to this integration is $\frac 1{4\sqrt3}$. Where did I go wrong? Thank you!

Comment: Your first denominator is squared, so the half should be squared

Comment: Check step 2 with the formula, again: $a\sin{x} + b\cos{x} = \sqrt{a^2 + b^2} \cos(x - \tan^{-1}{\frac{a}{b}})$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have that

\begin{equation*}
\left[\sqrt{3}\cos{(x)}+\sin{(x)}\right]^{2} = 4\cos^{2}{\left(x-\frac{\pi}{6}\right)},
\end{equation*}

so you're missing a factor of $2$. Otherwise, it looks good.